# How to pause background music when app is running in background

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I created a game.I added some background music to the app and now I want to pause the music when the app is exited using home button and the song should resume when it is opened from the multitasking.

```
package tssll8.coloursmash;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
Import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Created by ciddarth on 04/07/17.
 */

public class bgmusic extends Service {
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mediaplayer has a pause() method: [MediaPlayer#pause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause())

so you could call that in the on pause which gets triggered by pressing the home button, like so

```
public void onPause() {
    player.pause();
}
```

and resume it in onResume like this:

```
public void onResume() {
    player.play();
}
```